# In which Sutta, Buddha wore cloth of dead body?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, sutras, buddha

It is difficult for me to find the reference about Gautama Buddha wore robe made from cloth which was wrapped to a death body. Which part of Sutta do I have to reference?

Can we calculate how long Buddha wore this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in  [SN 16.11](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn16.11).

> ‘Your outer robe of patches is soft, Kassapa.’–‘Venerable sir, let the Blessed One accept my outer robe of patches, out of compassion.’–‘Then will you wear my worn-out hempen rag-robes? ’–‘I will, venerable sir.’ Thus I offered the Blessed One my outer robe of patches and received from him his worn-out hempen rag-robes.

However, the English translation doesn't mention that the Buddha wore a cloth wrapped to a dead body instead it just mentions *worn-out hempen rag-robes*. In the pali version it says the robe was *paṃsukūlāni* (rags discarded on the ground).

The Buddha has obtained it from the dead body of a servant named Punna lying in the cemetery (this part is in the commentary). He wore this robe until he exchanged it with Maha Kassapa.